# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serve

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I am trying to execute the following code but not sure where i am going wrong. Mysql workbench is throwing error for the following code

```
Insert into abc(Date,Close_Price,Signal)
Select
    Date,
    close_price,
    case 
        when dayma_20 > dayma_50 then 'BUY'
        when dayma_20 < dayma_50 then 'SELL'
        else 'HOLD'
    end as Signal
from stock;
```

It is giving error as follows:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Signal) Select date,close_price, case when dayma_20 > dayma_50 then 'BUY' when d' at line 1

Comment: It is not clear why you have quotes around insert before "from" clause. At any rate it seems to be a simple typo. If not, then reformat question properly please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGNAL` is a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). You need to enclose it between backticks (which, by the way, makes it case-sensitive, meaning that you must use the same case as the one that was used when the table was created).

```
insert into abc(Date,Close_Price,`Signal`) select ...
```

A better option would be rename that column to something that is not reserved. Using reserved words as object names in a schema is tedious and error prone.

Side note: `DATE` is also a reserved word.